# Grading a result system based on a column from a query

Tags: entity-framework, vb.net-2010

Please i have a project that i query the database using entity framework as my ORM. This is my query

```
    Dim subjectSearch = From subSearch In DemoSchool.EssenceSubjectRegistrations Where subSearch.Session = drpSession.SelectedItem.Text _
                      AndAlso subSearch.Term = drpTerm.SelectedItem.Text AndAlso subSearch.RealClass.ClassSN = findClassSN.FirstOrDefault AndAlso _
                       subSearch.SubjectCode = drpSubject.SelectedValue _
                       Select New With {.SubjectRegSN = subSearch.SubjectRegSN,
                                       .FirstName = subSearch.Student.FirstName,
                                       .Surname = subSearch.Student.Surname,
                                        .CA1 = subSearch.CA1,
                                         .CA2 = subSearch.CA2,
                                         .CA3 = subSearch.CA3,
                                         .CA4 = subSearch.CA4,
                                         .CA5 = subSearch.CA5,
                                         .CA6 = subSearch.CA6,
                                         .CA7 = subSearch.CA7,
                                         .CA8 = subSearch.CA8,
                                         .CA9 = subSearch.CA9,
                                         .CA10 = subSearch.CA10,
                                       .Exam = subSearch.Exam}
```

Then i query my result so that i can be able to do some operation on it by doing this

```
      Dim secSubjectSearch = (From jamie In subjectSearch Select jamie).ToList() _
                           .Select(Function(jamie) New With {.SubjectRegSN = jamie.SubjectRegSN,
                           .FirstName = jamie.FirstName,
                           .Surname = jamie.Surname,
                            .CA1 = jamie.CA1,
                             .CA2 = jamie.CA2,
                             .CA3 = jamie.CA3,
                             .CA4 = jamie.CA4,
                             .CA5 = jamie.CA5,
                             .MidTerm = CDbl(jamie.CA1 + jamie.CA2 + jamie.CA3 + jamie.CA4 + jamie.CA5) / 5,
                             .CA6 = jamie.CA6,
                             .CA7 = jamie.CA7,
                             .CA8 = jamie.CA8,
                             .CA9 = jamie.CA9,
                             .CA10 = jamie.CA10,
                              .Total = CDbl(jamie.CA1 + jamie.CA2 + jamie.CA3 + jamie.CA4 + _
                                       jamie.CA5 + jamie.CA6 + jamie.CA7 + jamie.CA8 + jamie.CA9 + jamie.CA10),
                            .Exam = jamie.Exam})
```

This result is bounded to a gridview control which displays the way it was suppose to.My problem is i want to create a column from the secSubjectSearch which will display the position of each person record in the search result. For example in the .Total= CDbl(jamie.CA1 + jamie.CA2 + jamie.CA3 + jamie.CA4 + _
                                           jamie.CA5 + jamie.CA6 + jamie.CA7 + jamie.CA8 + jamie.CA9 + jamie.CA10) the result is a numerical value which invovles adding the columns together.Let me say this is the result of the

```
    .Total aspect=(56,56,78,58,90,98,99) i want a column that gives the position of each persons record like 99-1
                                                       98-2
                                                       90-3
                                                       78-4
                                                       58-5
                                                       56-6
                                                       56-6
```

Like a kind of grading system based on a column in the search.Please i need help.If you need any more explanation please i will try more to elaborate my problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

What type of object is secSubjectSearch returning? If it's an entity as it looks like it should be, they're partial classes- you can create another partial class containing a property that calculates your values on the fly and it just becomes a virtual column.

Comment: please can you point out to me how to do what you suggested i forgot to mention that am still a beginner at this.

Comment: You say you're using EntityFramework; did you generate a model first- an edmx file that looks like a bunch of blocks representing tables and lines representing relationships between them? If so, along with the .edmx file there'll be a .Designer.cs file that contains code defining the classes that are your entities, representing the tables. Those classes are defined as *partial* which means if you have another class in the same project of the same name that's also defined as *partial* they'll merge to become one. This allows you to add functionality to the entities outside the model [contd]

Comment: so the new functionality isn't overwritten whenever the model is refreshed. So you can add extra properties- columns- that are derived from what you already have. Even if what you're deriving from is in a different file- as long as everything's part of the same class. So now you need to figure out what kind of object secSubjectSearch *is*. Easiest way is to breakpoint the code and use the debugger to tell you what class it is, then go and make another partial fragment of that class.

Comment: You've got to do *some* of the legwork yourself :) Start [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=entityframework+extending+entity+with+partial+classes) and ask further when you encounter specific issues.